# Problems rendering XML through XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

```
<ValueComponentIntervals>                         
  <ValueComponentInterval  Id="13095" >
    <RelateId>11840</RelateId>
    <RelateClass>cPriceQuoteInterval</RelateClass>
    <SourceId>11225</SourceId>
    <SourceClass>cHDProduct</SourceClass>
    <ParentId>11225</ParentId>
    <ParentClass>cHDProduct</ParentClass>
    <IntervalCount>20,170,601</IntervalCount>
    <ValueNum>50,000</ValueNum>
    <UnitOfMeasureCode>KH</UnitOfMeasureCode>
    <TimeStamp NativeString="20160215162241399"  UTCOffset="-300" >02/15/2016 04:22:41 PM</TimeStamp>
    <IntervalGroupCode>USG</IntervalGroupCode>
    <TypeCode>ACT</TypeCode>
    <DescriptionInfo>JUNE</DescriptionInfo>
    <VCITypeDescription>Actual VCI</VCITypeDescription>
    <Name>Usage</Name>
  </ValueComponentInterval>
  <ValueComponentInterval  Id="13096" >
    <RelateId>11840</RelateId>
    <RelateClass>cPriceQuoteInterval</RelateClass>
    <SourceId>11225</SourceId>
    <SourceClass>cHDProduct</SourceClass>
    <ParentId>11225</ParentId>
    <ParentClass>cHDProduct</ParentClass>
    <IntervalCount>20,170,601</IntervalCount>
    <ValueNum>0.0999</ValueNum>
    <UnitOfMeasureCode>USD</UnitOfMeasureCode>
    <TimeStamp NativeString="20160215162241399"  UTCOffset="-300" >02/15/2016 04:22:41 PM</TimeStamp>
    <IntervalGroupCode>GEN</IntervalGroupCode>
    <TypeCode>ACT</TypeCode>
    <DescriptionInfo>Fixed Price</DescriptionInfo>
    <VCITypeDescription>Actual VCI</VCITypeDescription>
    <Name>Price</Name>
  </ValueComponentInterval>
</ValueComponentIntervals>
```

I'm trying to render a table from the above XML block using an XSL template (below), but it won't work.

```
<xsl:for-each select="ValueComponentIntervals/ValueComponentInterval[Name = 'Usage']">
  <xsl:valueof select="ValueNum">
    <p>
      <span style="background-color:yellow; font-family:Arial; font-size:small">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </span>
    </p>
  </xsl:valueof>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The `Id`s are not consistent as they are auto-generated by a software package as are the TimeStamp Nativestrings.  I'm a bit new to XSLT/XML, and I'm stuck...

Update:

I have a varying number of ValueComponentInterval Blocks.  I am trying to select the blocks that only have a name of "USAGE" and return the value under "VALUENUM".

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish. May you please increase the preciseness of your question?

Comment: Please show a complete, minimal XSLT stylesheet with which we can reproduce your problem. Thanks. Help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Also say what XSLT processor or "software" you are referring to in the comments below and show the error you get.

Comment: Sorry, I've been in meetings.  It appears the above works completely for me now.  I must've missed a typo in my xslt file in "xsl:value-of".  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I adjusted this version and am pretty sure that this is what you try to accomplish (relating to a hypothetical root-node named `root` of which `ValueComponentIntervals` is a child):

```
<xsl:template match="/root">
  <xsl:for-each select="ValueComponentIntervals/ValueComponentInterval[Name = 'Usage']">
    <xsl:element name="p">
      <xsl:element name="span">
        <xsl:attribute name="style">background-color:yellow; font-family:Arial; font-size:small</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="ValueNum" />
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

The result of this is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p>
  <span style="background-color:yellow; font-family:Arial; font-size:small">50,000</span>
</p>
```

EDIT: Maybe this works better in your case.

Comment: That is exactly the outcome I'm looking for, but the software I'm using gives me an error of "xsl:value-of cannot be a child of span".

Comment: I presented another, more elaborate version with the same result.

Comment: Please use `xsl:element` only for dynamic element names (ones that are not known in advance). Otherwise, using `xsl:element` just makes XSLT even more verbose. Use a literal result element (e.g. `<p>`, `<span>`) instead. You do not need a hypothetical `root` element, you can make `/` the template match.

Comment: @Mathias Müller: My first answer before the edit was just like you described the 'ideal' XSLT. However, the questioner explicitly requested another approach in the comment above due to incompatibility to his environment. Transforming the `/root` template and the `xsl:for-each` loop to a single template is possible, but because the e.g. was incomplete, I chose a more verbose variant.

Comment: What I mean is match for `/` only: `<xsl:template match="/">` - you did not have that in your first edit. There is no reason to suppose that `<ValueComponentIntervals>` is not the outermost element of the OP's XML document. `xsl:element name="p"` instead of `p` will not fix the OP's problem. You already gave a good answer, now it is their turn to give enough information (a complete XSLT stylesheet) and if the software returns an error, we obviously need to know what software they are using.

Comment: @Mathias Müller: "`xsl:element name="p"` instead of `p` will not fix the OP's problem." - Yes, that's right, but as long as I don't know the real problem, I cannot fix it. Just I was saying in the original posting: "I'm just speculating..." Thanks for your input, though, regards.

Comment: Both your original and this are working for me now. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @George Todd: I' glad to read that. Have a nice time at StackOverflow. cu